# Android AutoCompleteTextView onClick problem

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've created an `AutoCompleteTextView` to search through a list of course titles (obtained from an sqlite db) and what I want to do is, when the user clicks on a title from the drop-down menu, the whole information from the database about his selection appears in a text view created below the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

I am pretty new to programming, especially for android and I would really appreciate it if someone could explain me how exactly to use `setOnItemClickListener` to call an instance in the database in the `TextView` below.

The code for the layout (R.layout.main_courses) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
<AutoCompleteTextView 
 android:id="@+id/autocomplete_course"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search for a course"/>
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/autocomplete_course"
    android:hint="Information about the course will appear here" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the code for the AutoCompleteTextView I've written so far is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main_courses);
    DataBase db = new DataBase(this.getApplicationContext());
 db.openDataBase();
 ArrayList<String> aCourses = db.getCoursesArr();
 db.close();


 AutoCompleteTextView search = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_course);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_courses, aCourses);
 search.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should try using a `CursorAdapter` instead of getting an array from it. Check [this link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/writing-your-own-autocompletetextview/) for more info.

There is a method in `AutoCompleteTextView` that let you decide how many letters the user must type before the dropdown is shown, [setThreshold](http://bit.ly/dITYFJ). The issue is that it only allows >=1 values.

If you check [this class src code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java), the good news is that the variable set by `setThreshold()` is only used in this method:

```
public boolean enoughToFilter() {
  return getText().length() >= mThreshold;
}
```

So the first thing I would try is extending `AutoCompleteTextView` and override that method to always return true.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that this might change in the future and it can get broken.